# How can you have Human Papillomavirus (HPV) in your body, but not in your throat?

Tags: virus, hpv

From this paper:

[Prevalence and concordance of oral and genital HPV in women positive for cervical HPV infection and in their sexual stable partners: An Italian screening study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6193646/)

> HPV was detected in 84% of Cervical Samples, in 24.3% of oral samples
> and in one urine sample.

It seems that it is possible to have genital HPV without having oral HPV. Maybe also vice versa.

How do viruses fundamentally work? I always thought that everything in the body is connected by the blood stream. Does this mean that the virus lives only inside the tissue cells, but never enters bloodstream?

Comment: Viruses aren't motile, so they're carried by whatever medium they're suspended in (serum, blood, mucus, etc) until they encounter a cell they're capable of infecting. Viruses often can only infect one or a few types of cells, so wherever those types of cells are found is where you'll find the viruses. That doesn't mean they didn't float around freely and go (almost) everywhere in the body before landing on a suitable host cell.

Comment: Getting a virus in your blood stream is not the usual condition of infection with most viruses. When that happens it's called [viremia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viremia). For example "Positive detection of viral RNA in blood and other non-respiratory specimens occurs in severe human influenza A/H5N1 viral infection but is not known to occur commonly in seasonal human influenza infection." https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0022534

Comment: Also, the title question is self-answered in the body of the question. As for the final question "How do viruses fundamentally work?" it seems to be too broad and lack prior research in that regard.